# Google apps script search in two columns get matching rows as 2D array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

the following gs code is working well

```
function getData00(e) {
  var id = "SHEET_ID";
  var sheetname = "SHEET";
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheetname).getDataRange().getValues();
  var ar = [];
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(e.color)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}
```

So i can search in column for specific "color" value and get the corresponding row values.
Now i need to add another criteria to search also in another column and get the combined row values.

my spreadsheet:

```
Number |   color   |   level   |   price   |   size   |   type
1      |   red     |   first   |    25     |    4     |   local
2      |   blue    |   third   |    30     |    3     |   global
3      |   green   |   second  |    40     |    6     |   local
4      |   blue    |   second  |    60     |    5     |   global
```

i need to search for "blue" in column B and for "local" in column F to get the matching rows values.

Result i am looking for:

```
2,blue,third,30,3,global
4,blue,second,60,5,global
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function dispData(ar) {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ar;
}
function getData00(e) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(dispData).getData00(e);    
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance and appreciate any help

Comment: Please don't edit your post to include follow up questions. If the answers below were useful, please accept one that solved your issue and ask another question.

Answer (score 3):

`Array.filter` would be more appropriate:

```
function getData01(e) {
  var id = "SHEET_ID";
  var sheetname = "SHEET";
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
    .getSheetByName(sheetname)
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues();
  return data.filter(row => [e.color, e.type].every(prop => row.includes(prop)))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Array.filter` to filter the source array to get the rows you want.

```
var matchingRows = data.filter(function(row){
    // check if column B equals "blue" and column F equals "local"
    return row[1] == "blue" && row[5] == "local";
});
```

Column B is in the 2nd place, which is the 1st index in the array for each row. Column F is in the 6th place, which is the 5th index in the array for each row.

Comment: Thank you Man so much, it works well with Logger.log(matchingRows) and i can see the data. BUT i cannot get the array in the html page